# Positioning divs with display flex and position fixed

Tags: css, flexbox, position

so I am trying to figure the following issue: given a top nav bar with position fixed, is there a way that the following down section doesn't get partially hidden by the navbar (because of the fixed position) by using "display: flex" and "align-items: center"? I know how to fix it by setting a margin-top equal to the height of the navbar to the section but I have seen that it can be also fixed in a more elegant manner by using display:flex and align-items:center and I would like to know if there is anybody who knows how to do that. I am attaching a codepen for the given situation. The problem is fixed with margin-top. Can you give an alternate solution to this issue using display: flex?

Here is the codepen code example:
https://codepen.io/buburuzza/pen/wvNWmBq

```
<div id="main">

  <div id="navbar">
  
    <ul style="display:inline-block;">
    <li style="display:inline-block; margin:10px;">Home</l>
    <li style="display:inline-block;margin:10px;">About</li>
    <li style="display:inline-block;margin:10px;">Contact</li>
    
  </ul>
  
</div> <!-- end navbar-->
        
            <div class="container">
              
              <div class="row" style="width:500px; margin:auto;">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed massa lectus, semper et diam et, finibus mattis orci. Aliquam volutpat dui ac quam sagittis, sed volutpat velit sollicitudin. Nullam at consectetur erat. Proin quis est pretium, volutpat tellus sit amet, lacinia ex. Nam vel massa sed dolor tincidunt imperdiet non quis lorem. Ut efficitur luctus vestibulum. Phasellus nec blandit turpis. Sed viverra quam vitae gravida tincidunt. Praesent interdum iaculis dolor, ac cursus quam semper sit amet. Ut sapien magna, vulputate at erat quis, congue fermentum tortor. Etiam neque ex, pellentesque at venenatis ac, sollicitudin ut quam. 
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- end main -->




  body {
    width:100%; margin:0; padding:0;
  
   }

   #main {
   width:100%; 
   height:auto;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;"
   }

   #navbar{
   display:block;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:fixed !important; 
   height:60px; 
   background-color:grey; 
   width:100%; 
   top:0;
   }

  .container {
  display:flex !important; 
  height:100%; 
  align-items: center !important;           
  background-color:yellow; 
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  margin-top:60px; /* HERE */
  
   }
```

Comment: Nope. The fixed position div is not affected by flexbox so you will need to use an alternative solution. Perhaps `position:sticky` instead but I'm not sure how this reacts with flexbox.

Comment: Fixed position element is completely removed from the document flow and placed relative to the viewport. In this case you can either use margin-top or padding-top to position the flex container as not to overlap. I don't think there are any flex container properties that could fix this overlapping problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
position: "sticky";
```

for the navbar and you won't need any margin.

Comment: This is the correct answer for fixing this issue; aligning the following div without using margin-top. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired layout without using the `margin-top` property by using flexbox. Here's an alternative solution using `display: flex` and `align-items: center`:

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed massa lectus, semper et diam et, finibus mattis orci. Aliquam volutpat dui ac quam sagittis, sed volutpat velit sollicitudin. Nullam at consectetur erat. Proin quis est pretium, volutpat tellus sit amet, lacinia ex. Nam vel massa sed dolor tincidunt imperdiet non quis lorem. Ut efficitur luctus vestibulum. Phasellus nec blandit turpis. Sed viverra quam vitae gravida tincidunt. Praesent interdum iaculis dolor, ac cursus quam semper sit amet. Ut sapien magna, vulputate at erat quis, congue fermentum tortor. Etiam neque ex, pellentesque at venenatis ac, sollicitudin ut quam.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

In this solution, I've used flexbox for both the `#navbar` and `.container`. The `#main` element is set to `display: flex` with a column direction to stack the `#navbar` and `.container` vertically. The `align-items: center` on both `#navbar` and `.container` ensures that the content is vertically centered, and you don't need to use `margin-top`.

Comment: When scroll, the navbar with position: "fixed" would stay at the top of the page. While in your solution, it won't.